# Volley Example Error Not in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to run a simple HTTP query through Volley and this code works completely fine in the default Android MainActivity under onCreate():

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // the response is already constructed as a JSONObject!
        try {
            //                   response = response.getJSONObject("results");
            String success = response.getString("success"),
                    status = response.getString("status");

            if(status.equals("1"))
            {
               GlobalVar.armedStatus = 1;
            }
            else if(status.equals("0"))
            {
                GlobalVar.armedStatus = 0;
            }

            System.out.println("Success: "+success+"\nStatus: "+status);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});
//    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(jsonRequest);
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

When I run this code in a separate class though, the final line gives an error.

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

The error on `newRequestQueue` is "Cannot resolve symbol 'newRequestQueue' and the error on `add(jsonRequest);` is "Missing method body, or declare abstract."

Any help would be appreciated, not sure why it works in the Activity, but not in the class file... I assume the reason is onCreate(), but I'm sure there is some way to keep it in another class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in the line:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

The `this` you pass into `newRequestQueue()` needs to be an Android Context.  When you're calling it from your Activity then `this` refers to the Activity which is a type of Context.  When you call if from your own class it will refer to that class which won't be a Context.

You have a few different options:

**Add Context as a Constructor Parameter for your Object**

You can have it so that when you make an instance of your class you have to pass in a context which you hold onto.  This would then be used when you call Volley:

```
public class MyClass {

    private Context context;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void doVolleyRequest() {

        //...
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jsonRequest);
    }

}
```

Then when you make your class from your Activity you would have to instantiate it like:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
```

**Have a static Reference to the Application Context**

You can have a static reference to the Application Context which can be accessed from your Application class.  To do this in your Application Class have something like:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Then from your class where you are using Volley:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(App.getContext()).add(jsonRequest);
```

**Have an App Wide RequestQueue**

Instead you could set up a request queue in your Application class and add all requests to that:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return requestQueue;
    }
}
```

Then in your class:

```
App.getRequestQueue().add(jsonRequest);
```